# Can I instruct bazel to emit a ".elf" suffix to executables?

Tags: bazel

`cc_binary` (on osx / linux) creates executables with no suffix. This makes sense, since the standard on those platforms is to not use extensions.

When using Bazel as a cross-compiler through a custom CROSSTOOL, though, I'd like Bazel to emit an elf file with an explicit `.elf` suffix.

Is this possible, either through CROSSTOOL or a custom "rename" rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name your cc_binary 'foo.elf' and bazel will just build it. Or you can use genrule to do the renaming afterwards.

Now if you need to build the same cc_binary with multiple toolchains, each time producing a different extension, that's a little bit more tricky. But genrule will work there too.

Comment: Thanks, I was totally overthinking it and trying to figure out how to do it in CROSSTOOL. I need a native rule anyway since I'll be invoking cc_binary and working with the output, so I'll just tack an ".elf" into the output file parameter there.