# Rename bazel output (extension) after build

Tags: maya, bazel, maya-api

I see there's a thread where this has been discussed already, but a bit vaguely:

[Can I instruct bazel to emit a ".elf" suffix to executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598017/can-i-instruct-bazel-to-emit-a-elf-suffix-to-executables)

Unfortunately that doesn't help in my case. I am trying to compile plugins for Autodesk Maya on windows using Bazel, so my output needs to be a `.dll` file with custom extension `.mll`. Here's an example code of how my BUILD file is setup:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "myPlugin.dll",  # can't rename this to .mll, otherwise bazel won't build
    srcs = glob(
        [
            "myPlugin.h",
            "myPlugin.cpp",
        ]
    ),
    deps = [
        "@maya_repo//:Foundation",
        "@maya_repo//:OpenMaya",
    ],
    linkopts = [
        "-export:initializePlugin",
        "-export:uninitializePlugin",
    ],
    linkshared = True,
)
```

Everything compiles, but I can't seem to find a way to rename the extension to `.mll`, I tried documenting on `genrules` but I couldn't make it work.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
genrule(
   name = "plugin_mll",
   srcs = ["myPlugin.dll"],
   outs = ["myPlugin.mll"],
   cmd = "cp $(location myPlugin.dll) $(location myPlugin.mll)",
)
```

or with the Make variables:

```
genrule(
   name = "plugin_mll",
   srcs = ["myPlugin.dll"],
   outs = ["myPlugin.mll"],
   cmd = "cp $< $@",
)
```

and then run `bazel build //path/to/package:plugin_mll` to invoke the genrule, or `bazel build //path/to/package:myPlugin.mll` to build the file target directly.

Comment: thanks for your answer! However I think I have another issue to solve before I can get it working: currently myPlugin.dll outputs three files, basically it copies .dll files from Maya that it depends on (OpenMaya.dll, Foundation.dll) other than generating my output. So when I do cp `($location myPlugin.dll)` it says that there are multiple outputs, but I can't find a way to tell Bazel to avoid putting those extra libs in there. Is that possible?

Comment: Ha, found out what the problem was, I had to use `tools = [":myPlugin.dll"]` to make it work, so that it won't consider the external libraries. Thanks a lot for your help!